# Using cssutils to access or read the properties of page rule

Tags: python, css

I have read/write the properties of Font_face rule and style rule in css file.
Using the cssutils version 0.9.6 and programming language in python.
I try to read ,access the property of page rule.
But it gives problem for reading the property in page_rule style sheet.the property in the page rule gives the type as unknown rule.
So how can i read the property of page rule 
I got while parsing the css files the selectorText/class name as :blank property.atkeyword as  @top-left @top-center
But not get the property namely content and values of those property ?
for ex as the lines in css files as :

```
  @page:blank {
   @top-left { 
       content: normal;
       }
   @top-center { 
       content: normal;
      }
   }
```

I want to read the property content and value as normal and all this using the cssutils not by using the regular expressions

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for [css page rule](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-page/) selectors is:

```
@page [identifier][:(first|left|right)]
```

So the example given in the question is invalid, because "blank" is not a `pseudo-page`.

You possibly meant:

```
@page blank {
    @top-left { 
       content: normal;
       }
    @top-center { 
       content: normal;
      }
}
```

which `cssutils` parses correctly.